# How do I show only commits that have differences with git?

Tags: git, github, diff, git-diff

I have this behemoth branch that we needed to only deploy a few files from. We ended up doing a checkout of the files we wanted to deploy and abandoning the history. Now I'd like to make a compare of the behemoth branch against master but only show the commits that actually have code diffs. So if a commit only changes a file that was checked out then that commit has no code changes and id like for it to not show on the diff. Is that possible? How?

EDIT: Maybe if there is a way to show the diff between files only and ignore all commits?

EDIT 2: The reason is that I would like to minimize history loss so I was trying to find just the commits that i actually need to cherry pick/rebase into master

Comment: Could you start by demonstrating any existing commands you know of and how they do not apply to your situation? It might make it easier to understand your scenario

Comment: right now im using github's diff and it has a bunch of commits that i know have no code diff from master

Answer (score 1):

If you just want commits that touched a specific file, `git log -- <path>` and you can name one or more files in the < path> or use wildcards. `git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]` to list file diffs between two versions (commits). Is that what you want?

Comment: thanks ill try that in a minute but i think this is what i was looking for :)